# Django object filter based on file url

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have problems to filter my object based on file url/path

I want make simple system to let only staff download files from specific folder(media/client/files).

I wrote regex in urls and every request go to file_get_url view where I check if this file exist in File model based on filter by url - but i don't know how to filter with this. When i get object i have "file.url" but not in filter(file_url). Do u have idea how resolve this problem?

**Urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^media/client/files/', 'file.views.file_get_url', name='file_get_url'),
]
```

**Views.py:**

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_staff, login_url='/account/login/')
def file_get_url(request):
    if request.user.is_staff:
        f = File.objects.filter(file_url=request.get_full_path())
        return HttpResponse(f.file.url)
```

**Models.py**

```
class File(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='client/files/')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=32, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    object_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=False, default=None)
    content_id = models.IntegerField(default=None, null=False, blank=False)
```

Comment: You dont get anything because file_url is not a field in File model

Comment: Also, in your models you have mentioned that file should be uploaded to '/client/files' and you want staff users to download it only from there. So whats the problem? Forgive me, but I am not really seeing a problem here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using two views one for files direct based on path and one based on file_id. Maybe for someone will be helpful :)

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_staff, login_url='/account/login/')
    def file_get_url(request):
        file_path = request.get_full_path()[1:]  # to remove '/'
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):  # to check if this file(based on path) exist there!
            response = HttpResponse(FixedFileWrapper(open(file_path, 'rb')), content_type=mimetypes.guess_type(file_path)[0])
            response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(file_path)
            response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % os.path.basename(file_path)
            return response
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Nothing exist here!')

@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_staff, login_url='/account/login/')
def file_get(request, file_id):
    f = File.objects.get(id=file_id)
    file_path = f.file.url[1:]

    response = HttpResponse(FixedFileWrapper(open(file_path, 'rb')), content_type=f.type)
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(file_path)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % os.path.basename(file_path)
    return response
```